# Adobe Air Android renderMode direct and Textinput

Tags: android, apache-flex, air, adobe

It would seem that using the  DIRECT prevents an Air mobile app from using a soft keybord to enter text in a TextInput field. This  has been tested on a Samsung Galaxy S3.  Is there a workaround for this bug or am I missing something?